# Rank of a stochastic matrix $+$ the identity matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, stochastic-matrices

I have a row-stochastic matrix $G\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, such that $n<m$ and $Rank(G)<n.$ Define $J\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ as follows.

$$ J_{i,j} = \begin{cases} 1 & i=j,i\in [n]\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

Is it true that the rank of $(1-\epsilon)\times G+\epsilon\times J$ for $\epsilon>0$ is $n$?

Comment: How can you add a non-square matrix $(1-\epsilon)G$ to a square matrix $\epsilon I_n$?

Comment: Thanks! I meant adding a matrix $J\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ such that $J_{i,i}=1$ $\forall i\in [n]$ and $0$ otherwise. So $J$ is the $I_n$ matrix ``padded" with zeros. I will clarify.

Comment: If you mean to specify that $\epsilon>0$ [or just $\epsilon\ne 0$] then you should do so.

Answer (score 1):

No. Here is a random counterexample generated by computer:
$$
\epsilon=\frac15\ \text{ and }\ G=\frac{1}{12}\pmatrix{4&4&1&3\\ 1&1&7&3\\ 4&4&1&3}.
$$
We have
\begin{aligned}
\pmatrix{1&1&-2}\left[(1-\epsilon)G+\epsilon J\right]
&=\frac{1}{5}\pmatrix{1&1&-2}(4G+J)\\
&=\frac{1}{15}\pmatrix{1&1&-2}(12G+3J)\\
&=\frac{1}{15}\pmatrix{1&1&-2}\pmatrix{7&4&1&3\\ 1&4&7&3\\ 4&4&4&3}\\
&=0.
\end{aligned}